# es2018 vs es2018.promise vs es2018.regexp

Tags: javascript, typescript

TypeScript compiler has the [following options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) for the `--lib` cmd line arg:

- ES2018
- ES2018.Promise
- ES2018.RegExp

What is the difference between them? Should I use `ES2018` or `ES2018.Promise` if I need `Promisefinally()` support only and do NOT care about other ES2018 features?

Also, since what TS version those `ES2018` libs are supported? When I try to use them with TS 2.6.2, it throws:

> Error: tsconfig.json(16,13): error TS6046: Argument for '--lib' option
>   must be: 'es5', 'es6', 'es2015', 'es7', 'es2016', 'es2017', 'esnext',
>   'dom', 'dom.iterable', 'webworker', 'scripthost', 'es2015.core',
>   'es2015.collection', 'es2015.generator', 'es2015.iterable',
>   'es2015.promise', 'es2015.proxy', 'es2015.reflect', 'es2015.symbol',
>   'es2015.symbol.wellknown', 'es2016.array.include', 'es2017.object',
>   'es2017.sharedmemory', 'es2017.string', 'es2017.intl',
>   'esnext.asynciterable'.

Comment: Correct. ES2018 includes AFAIK object rest, Promise.finally, and the regex stuff: named capture groups, lookbehinds, s-flag, and unicode script attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lib` option only provide typing for these libraries. If you specify `ES2018` than you will get `ES2018` typing even if you target for ES2015. By default, TypeScript sets some libs depending on which target you specify but it allows you since version 2.0 to manually add more typing.

> What is the difference between them?

They are a subset of different families of features.

> Should I use ES2018 or ES2018.Promise if I need Promisefinally() 
>   support only and do NOT care about other ES2018 features?

Yes, you are can scope to what you need. However, it won't increase your generated JavaScript if you include more.

> Since what TS version those ES2018 libs are supported?

If you are using a target that does not support a feature natively, you may download (npm) a package to Polyfill. It's not related directly to a TS version.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Does it mean that `ES2018.Promise` option enables support for all ES2017 features + ES2018 promises only, not the rest of ES2018 features?

Comment: Also regarding the TS version that supports ES2018: please see my updated question. I think they introduced `ES2018.*` cmd line args in some newer version than TS 2.6.2. So, we have to use a certain minimal version of TS to be able to use ES2018 features.

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov did you solve it out? I tried to include both `es2018` and `es2018.promise`, but `Promise.finally()` still not available. Do I need to include some library manually in the code maybe?